# Public Site - Metadata API - Site under construction Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, metadata-api

I am using Metadata API through Salesforce public site.

I am getting the following error from public site.

> Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault:
>   UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Site under construction faultcode=UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION
>   faultactor=

Session Id is currently hardcoded. Anyone faced the same issue before?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: This can sometimes mean you're not referencing the site extension in the url, meaning using `http://companyname.cs99.force.com/` when you need to be using `http://companyname.cs99.force.com/publicsite`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was because of the wrong site extension url.

By default MetaDataAPI endpoint was http://companyname.cs99.force.com/ instead of the actual site extension url http://companyname.cs99.force.com/publicsite.

I changed the EndPoint with actual site extension url and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the site prefix with `'{!$Site.Prefix}'` is the correct answer, but I found that creating another dummy community in salesforce with an empty path (so no `/publicsite`) also works. My guess is that each community site doesn't care that the site prefix matches, just that it exists.